# adding a API in c project

Tags: c

I am trying to use a little piece of code written by someone else in my c program. In the piece of code there is a function used whose declaration is

```
ascii * wm_strGetParameterString ( ascii * dst, const ascii * src, u8 Position );
```

This function is defined in a header file named wm_stdio.h. At the moment i am getting the compiler error. How can i make use of this function. Adding the header file wm_stdio.h in my existing c Project will do the trick ? or do i have to do something else. thanku

compiler error: implicit declaration of function `wm_strGetParameterString'

Comment: "The compiler  error", because theres only one and everybody knows what it is.

Comment: Please read a c book for beginners! There are two different views: What your compiler reads and what your ide need.

Comment: I just hate it when I get The Compiler Error.

Comment: To OP to learn about this topic you could read sections 2, 3 and 6 of the following: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Don't you think that the *actual error* you're getting would be useful information?

That said, you're probably getting an "undefined reference"-type error from your linker. You must provide an implementation, just including the header is not enough.

**EDIT**: If you're getting "implicit declaration", then yes you must add an `#include` to the C file that references that function.